# How do i get all Sunday dates in a particular year?

Tags: java

**Exact duplicate:** [How to get all dates of sundays in a particular year in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590385/how-to-get-all-dates-of-sundays-in-a-particular-year-in-java)

---

```
int year = 2009;
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
for (int i = 0, inc = 1; i < 366 && cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year; i+=inc) {
    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        // this is a sunday
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); 
        inc = 7;
    } else {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
}
```

In [Miles D given code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590385/how-to-get-all-dates-of-sundays-in-a-particular-year-in-java/590447#590447), I am getting dates of all sundays from second sunday of frst month to frst sunday of next year. Actually I am looking for a particular year only, and its all sunday dates, plz miles can u see it once again.....

For instance, I need all sunday dates in 2009 from January 2009 to December 2009 only

Comment: for instance, i need all sunday dates of 2009 from jan-2009 to dec-2009 only,

Comment: What is it with the close vote?

Comment: @chakrit: It's a duplicate question.

Comment: For the record, I think an answer is a far better place for a duplicate link than plastering it at the top of the question.

Comment: I'd usually agree, but this seems a lot like 'give me da codz', especially since "subhash" looks like a user created to hide that this is a duplicate question by "subhash4all".

Comment: Now that I look at it, there's actually two "subhash" users - one which answered the other's question. Hmm.

Comment: Gosh, it got closed! And after all that writing, too! :-)

Answer (score 2):

New to programming? Well, let's have a look at the code together!

The first thing that I see is the conditional inside the loop:

```
if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
```

This checks if the current date stored in the Calendar `cal` has a `DAY_OF_WEEK` which is `SUNDAY`. If it is, it does one thing, and if it isn't, it does another.

Now that we know what the loop's "brain" is looking for, let's look at the loop's declaration:

```
for (int i = 0, inc = 1; i < 366 && cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year; i+=inc)
```

The `for` loop is split into three parts: initialization, condition, and "increment".
The initialization, is run only once, before th loop starts running:

```
int i = 0, inc = 1
```

Which, as I'm *sure* you know, creates two variables: `i` and `inc`. It sets `i` to 0, and `inc` to 1.

The condition of the loop gets checked before running each iteration of the loop. It is:

```
i < 366 && cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year
```

Which checks whether `i` is still less than 366 and also that the date stored in `cal` has the `YEAR` of `year`. This, in effect, makes sure we are still in the same year we started with.

The last section of the for, is this:

```
i+=inc
```

Which adds the value of `inc` to the value of `i` and stores it in `i`.

So what do we have so far in the loop?

1. The loop starts with an `i` of 0 and an `inc` of 1
2. The loop keeps going as long as

   - `i` is smaller than the length of a Gregorian year (366 on leap-years),
   - (AND) the date in `cal` still has the same year as the year in `year`.
3. `i` is advanced by `inc`

Let's have another look at the body of the loop:

```
if (condition_that_checks_if_it_is_a_sunday) {
    // this is a sunday
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); 
    inc = 7;
} else {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

As you can see, if it's a Sunday, two things happen: `inc` is set to 7, and 7 `DAY_OF_MONTH` are `add`ed to `cal`. This would mean that in the next iteration of the loop, the expression `i+=inc` will mean `i+=7` and not `i+=1` which is did when `inc` was 1 (like it was when the initialization was done.)

If it's not a Sunday, a single `DAY_OF_WEEK` is added to `cal`.

So what do we have in the body of the loop?

- Check if `cal` is a Sunday

  - If it is, advance `cal` by 7 days. And not only that, but keep advancing `i` by 7!
  - If `cal` isn't on a sunday, advance it to the next day of the week, and let `i` keep advancing by 1.

In other words, the loop will start at `cal`'s initial value, and move `cal` forward one day at a time until it finds a Sunday. Once it does that, it will move `cal` forward 7 days at a time, until it has gone over 366 days, or until `cal` is in another year!

Thus, from (*ahem*) briefly examining the code above, we an conclude it doesn't actually "get" the Sundays in a year. It simply iterates over them, and it's up to you to add the code that actually does something with the Sundays it finds.

And now that we've gone over the code together, I'm certain it's trivial to do that! It really is a matter of just adding a couple of lines. You just have to add a line that does [insert here whatever you want] every time the loop enters the part where it "knows" `cal` is a Sunday.

Simple, no?

Comment: +1 for the effort =D Btw, I don't think the OP said anything about counting the Sundays.

Comment: Darnit, you're absolutly right!

Comment: Hai Scraimer...thanks for ur explanation,but am bit aware of programing,all i expecting from u is.need the exact code for my requuiremnt,actully this code is given by one dude,but it's not giving output,i need all dates of sundays(52/53 sunday dates) in a year,thats it,can u Do it for me

Comment: @scraimer: Guess that confirms your suspicions ;)

Comment: Nope. This site isn't about giving code, it's about giving programmers advice on how to figure out how to do things themselves... I was hoping you would have understood that from my answer.

Comment: ok Scraimer,aftr all am a Student how can i get that think quickly..so finally u r words saying indirectly "StackOverFlow cant helps 100%"

Answer (score 1):

Here's the algorithm I might start with (code is left as an exercise for the reader):

Find a Sunday closest to a specific date. For example, start from Jan 1 and walk forward until you find a Sunday. This should cost no more than 7 operations.

Now that you know a Sunday, you can calculate all of the other ones from Julian dates based on that one simply by adding multiples of 7 to the first Sunday.

You should also calculate the closest Sunday backward from Dec 31, so that you know when to stop including Sundays in your chosen year.

Oh, having just written that, I see that [someone else had the same idea already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590385/how-to-get-all-dates-of-sundays-in-a-particular-year-in-java/590427#590427).

Comment: thanks for your kind suggestion my dear Craig S,but exactly am looking for code to get all date of sundays in a selected year.