# How to get the date of every sunday

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all dates of sundays in a particular year in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590385/how-to-get-all-dates-of-sundays-in-a-particular-year-in-java)

How can I get the date of the coming Sunday?, I am creating a time sheet system so I would like to always get the next Sunday date... until the date has passed..

so if it's Monday it should give me the date of the next Sunday, and on Monday 12:00 am, the next next Sunday and etc...

How can I do this in java?, to always get the next Sunday date?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

using java.util.Calendar:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    while(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY){
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Next sunday is " + cal.getTime());
```